# Building Cordova Project with Proguard enabled

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-proguard

When compiling my App using Cordova with Proguard enabled I receive warning:

***Can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] - Duplicate Zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]***

This is due to the duplication of libraries inside the folder 'platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build'.
Inside the folder there are 'classes.jar' file and the unzipped containts of the file in the 'classes' folder.
I tried remove it, but both are generated when compiling again, so the warning persists.

Reading similar questions, I have tried several combinations of '-keep' and '-dontwarn- in the 'proguard-android-optimize.txt' file but no lucky. The last:

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.DroidGap 
-keep class org.apache.cordova.** { *; }
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.webkit.*
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.classes.**
```

So, how must I avoid the duplication?
Additionally, I also receive the following notes from the Proguard when compile:

***The configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingServices'.
The configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingServices***

I am using Cordova 4.3.

Any help would be appreciate.
Thank you.